# $u,v,w\in R^n, \text{ } \|u\| = \|w\| = 7, \text{ } \|v\| = 1, \text{ } \|u - v + w\| = \|u + v + w\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$u,v,w\in R^n, \text{ } \|u\| = \|w\| = 7, \text{ } \|v\| = 1, \text{ } \|u - v + w\| = \|u + v + w\| \text{ }$

The angle between $u$, $v$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

**What is the angle between $v$, $w$ ?**

This is what i have:

Let $s = v + w$

$\|u - s\| = \|u + s\|$

Using the Polarization identity

$u \cdot s = \frac{1}{4} (\|u + s \|^2 - \|u - s\|^2)$

$u \cdot s = 0$

$u \cdot (v + w) = 0$

$u \cdot v + u \cdot w = 0$

$u \cdot v = -(u \cdot w)$

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) \|u\| \|v\| = -\cos(\alpha) \|u\| \|w\|$

$\alpha = \arccos(-\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) \|v\|}{\|w\|})$

$\alpha = \arccos(-\frac{1}{14})$

$\alpha\text{ }$ is the angle between $u$, $w$

**How do i find the angle between $v$, $w$ ?**

Comment: Some things to think about.  Since u, w have equal magnitude, $u+w$ is the diagonal of a rhombus formed by $u$ and $w.$  What angle does $u+w$ form with $u, w$?  And I suggest $\|(u+w)-v\| = \|(u+w)+v\|$ implies that $v$ is perpendicular to $u+w.$  I will leave it to you to prove it.

Comment: This helped $∥(u+w)−v∥=∥(u+w)+v∥$. Thanks @Doug M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring both sides of $\left \| u-v+w \right \|=\left \| u+v+w \right \|$ yields after canceling $\left \| \cdot\right \|^2$s
$$-2u\cdot v-2w\cdot v+2u\cdot w=2u\cdot v+2w\cdot v+2u\cdot w$$
And so $w\cdot v = -u\cdot w$. From here use the definition of the dot product like you did.

Edit: There's an algebric mistake. are you sure there isn't a degree of freedom for the angle?

Comment: "There's an algebric mistake. are you sure there isn't a degree of freedom for the angle?" Where is the mistake?  I got $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ as the answer. @Theorem

Comment: I was mistaken later thinking you wanted to find $u \cdot w$. There isn't a degree of freedom, but I did cancel out the wrong term. The correct result is $w\cdot v = - u \cdot v$, indeed yielding $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.